# Trying to open a Workbook and a run a macro in that file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook which opens up another workbook (filename is based on a cell value) and then runs a macro called Single_sector within that file.

It opens the file perfectly fine but doesn't run the macro. Any ideas?

```
Sub run_all()
Dim Location



On Error Resume Next

'Location of file to open
 Location = Worksheets("Main").Range("folder_location").Value

'Open F&V File
Application.Workbooks.Open Location & Range("fv_file").Value
'Run Macro
Run ("Single_sector")



End Sub
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Place the following code in the macro calling the other workbook:

```
Location = Worksheets("Main").Range("folder_location").Value
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Location & Range("fv_file").Value)
Application.Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!" & strSubToRun, Parameters
Set wb = Nothing
```

Parameters is an array of arguments that you want to pass, so the sub in the other workbook should look something like

```
Public Sub TheSub(ParamArray X())

Dim i As Long

Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Parameters passed:"

For i = 0 To UBound(X(0))
    Sheet1.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value = CStr(X(i))
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: does macro 'strSubToRun' in wb workbook works in asynchronous manner ?

Answer (score 4):

Probably not very elegant but:

```
Dim Location As String

Location = "\\location\to\file.xlsm"

Workbooks.Open(Location).RunAutoMacros (xlAutoOpen)
```

Where you have an Auto_Open Sub in your other excel file to handle the macros to run on your other spreadsheet

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Please make sure your code in another workbook is at Workbook_open event so you dont need to use Run ("Single_sector"). The procedure single_selector would trigger as soon as another workbook is open.

Updated answer

```
Sub run_all()
    Dim Location



    On Error Resume Next

    Dim wkb As Workbook

    'Location of file to open
    Location = Worksheets("Main").Range("folder_location").Value

    'Open F&V File
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Location & Range("fv_file").Value)
    wkb.Sheets(1).Single_sector ' kindly put this proc in another workbook sheet1




End Sub
```

Comment: The only problem with that is that I need to do some things in the file sometimes so having the macro run whenever I open the file would not be the best solution.

Comment: So when all that things  is over you open the another workbook.

Comment: Where does your code reside in another workbook. Module or worksheet ??

Comment: The things I need to do/ change are in the other workbook. The code is in a module is the other workbook. Thanks

Comment: Pls elaborate what kind of change so that i can help you.

Comment: I just meant that in the Other sheet, I may go in a paste in some data etc independant of this macro scenerio. If single_sector is run when the file is open, it would help with the question above but not in my day to day workflow as everytime i open the "Other workbook", it would run the macro. I just need the macro single_sector to be run after I open the workbook programatically. Thanks for your help.