# Hiding the Excel application during run-time

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to hide Excel during a long script in which I do some web-scraping. I'm able to hide the application just fine, the problem is that when I change `.Visible` back to `True`, I'm getting 1-2 more additional applications (just empty Excel shells). I'm guessing one of these are my `PERSONAL.xlsb` workbook, but I'm not sure what the other one is - sometimes I get one extra, sometimes I get two. The only way I can close these shell files is by ending the `EXCEL.EXE` process via task manager.

I've tried hiding just the main window (`Windows(1)`) as well to no avail (it just hides the workbook, not the application):

```
Sub Test()

Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = False

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = True

End Sub
```

**How can I just have my main workbook re-appear?**

Sample code:

```
Sub Test()

Application.Visible = False

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Application.Visible = True

End Sub
```

[image]

Edit: This is on Windows 7, Excel 2016

Edit2: Running just `Application.Visible = True` by itself also gives me these two phantom applications.

Edit3: The issue definitely has to do with having macros stored in the `PERSONAL.xlsb` file - when I go onto a fresh computer and add a new macro to this workbook, I can reproduce the issue. However, I'm still not sure how to avoid it...

Task manager:

[image: img1]

The script that opens Excel from Filemaker Pro:

`Open URL [With dialog:Off; "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\TestFile.xlsm"]`

Inside `TestFile.xlsm`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.Visible = False

'Refresh a query in the Excel workbook that is linked to Filemaker Pro

'Webscrape, webscrape, webscrape from a worksheet inside this Excel document
'to a hidden Internet Explorer Window (ewww, IE!)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Application.Visible = True

'Either close Excel completely or reload my main instance of Excel

End Sub
```

**I've realized that I can just completely quit Excel with Excel.Application.Quit, but I haven't decided if I want to exit out right away, or repaint a UserForm in Excel that summarizes the import process**

Comment: I stopped answering VBA web-scraping questions because I am now totally convinced that the best strategy is to use a Chrome Extension, see here https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/06/python-javascript-mutationobserver_8.html and if you are wondering how to get the data into an Excel.exe then turn it into a web server with this https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/03/vba-c-excel-as-web-server-with-rest.html  ... just some friendly advice.

Comment: @SMeaden Thanks for the advice, however I think it's a bit irrelevant in this scenario.

Comment: Ok, "when I go onto a fresh computer and add a new macro to this workbook, I can reproduce the issue."  what is in that macro?  I think the problematic code is not present in the text of the question.

Comment: @SMeaden The code in the workbook is entirely web-scraping, so I've omitted it. I'm essentially trying to open Excel from another program (Filemaker Pro) and run this web-scraping code from Excel without the user ever seeing Excel (as it's the middle man).

Comment: How are you instantiating Excel? A new Excel.Application shouldn't be visible by default.

Comment: @dwirony you will need to shows us some more code - no need to include all the web scraping stuff, but do include all code that creates/references the Excel app, and any code that opens/closes workbooks, including code in Filemaker, and an [MCVE] of any code in Excel

Comment: @Comintern Opening the Excel workbook from Filemaker Pro.

Comment: @dwirony - Using what code?

Comment: @chrisneilsen I've added a larger scope of how my process is laid out.

Comment: @Comintern I've edited my question with the script.

Comment: If you're shelling Excel, it's just like opening it manually. Can you shell a .vbs to open it instead?

Comment: @Comintern Possibly... I'll have to look more into the capabilities of FMP... So you think using a .vbs script will trigger my `Workbook_Open` event?

Comment: It should - the workaround seems to be open Excel in a way in which it isn't visible ever, and you can do that with VBS. If you're using `Workbook_Open` *only* to hide the application, it would be irrelevant.

Comment: @Comintern Hmmm so I can use `Send Event` script in FMP to open the Excel application; it opens Excel without bringing it the foreground, but I can still see on my taskbar that the application itself is open...

Comment: I'm not familiar with FMP at all. Does it let you do something like `Open URL [With dialog:Off; "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\MyScript.vbs"]`?

Comment: @Comintern Conversely I'm not familiar with vbscript at all - but it looks like I can use `Send Event` to run a text file containing a vbscript? It just feels like I'm straying away too far here...

Comment: I have done this years ago without getting the symptoms you are experiencing.  I will post the answer when I get home tonight hopefully before the deadline.

Comment: @Dwirony Please see my answer below.  I have suggested a possible explanation for why you are seeing a third instance and suggested a solution to prevent it.  I suspect that you may not be shutting down Excel in code properly.  You may be hiding it, instead.  So when you execute Applicatio.visible = true, you see the previous instance which was never shut down or unloaded from memory.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to reproduce your issue. First, I tested hiding the Application without having PERSONAL.xlsb loaded, and it worked fine. Then I loaded PERSONAL.xlsb and got the same behavior you did: an extra Excel shell became visible after Application.Visible = True.

I'm not sure why you sometimes get two extra shells, but maybe you have another addin (.xlam) loaded? You could try adding some code to unload all addins first, but I have an alternative solution: why not just launch a new instance of Excel, load your macro workbook in it and run the macro? For example, if your workbook is called C:\Book1.xlsb and the macro in it is "MyMacro" then create a second workbook with code that will launch Book1. Like this:

```
Sub LaunchIt()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

    With xlApp
        Set wb = .Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsb")
        .Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!MyMacro"
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

The new instance of Excel is not visible by default, so no need to set visibility. I tested it and it worked for me.

Comment: If you need to pass parameters to your macro I explain how to do that in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15203389/1523914.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will suffice, since I am trying to stealthily load and hide Excel from another program. If I open a new instance of Excel, won't I still see my old shell of Excel still open?

Comment: Are you trying to hide all instances of Excel or just the one doing the screen-scraping?  If what you're trying to do is to hide everything, then do the screen scrape and then restore any other instances of Excel to their prior visible state, you're going to have to capture all the other instances of Excel and their Visible state and then once you have finished your screen-scraping process, restore each instance to it's prior state.  If you just want to hide the instance of Excel that's running the screen-scraping, then @ExcelDevelopers solution should work.

Comment: @FrankBall I want to hide all instances of Excel, which should just be one instance as Excel won't even be open to begin with.

Comment: So if a user is running this and they already have an open instance of Excel, how do you want to handle that?  If this isn't being ran by  user, then what's the need for hiding Excel?

Comment: @FrankBall A user will be running this. And I haven't anticipated what will happen if they already have Excel open, I'd have to tell them ahead of time to not have it open...

Comment: Then you may want to take a look at this:  https://excelribbon.tips.net/T009452_Finding_Other_Instances_of_Excel_in_a_Macro.html

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this behavior also, but setting the Visible-property of the window to false will solve it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim x As Workbook
With Application
    .Visible = False
    .Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    .Visible = True
        For Each x In .Workbooks
            If x.Name = "PERSONAL.XLSB" Then 'maybe also other addins(?)
                x.Windows(1).Visible = True
                x.Windows(1).Visible = False 'toggle
                x.Saved = True 'for not getting save-alerts
            End If
        Next
End With
End Sub
```

Edit:

or changing the for each loop to:

```
    For Each myAdd In AddIns
        myAdd.Installed = False
    Next myAdd
```

works on my side (But: on closing you've to set your previous installed addins back to True)

Comment: All 3 excels still show up, then I get a subscript out of range on line `x.Windows(1).Visible = True`.

Comment: So there is a PERSONAL.XLSB on the background opened, strange, it works on my side . Just added a for each loop in previous answer as another workaround.

Comment: Changed the `For Each` loop, still the same results with no error. 3 Excel applications.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, you wish to go invisible to the user during a particular operation then reappear once that operation has completed?

If so, then take a look at the code I used to make my application actually start with Excel invisible with only a particular form on show:

When the user has finished and wishes to quit the application, he presses cmdQuit command button.  The code behind this would make Excel re-appear:  Code pasted below.  I hope this helps to inspire you to find the solution for your situation.

**Notes:**

1.  Ideally we would like to make the entire excel invisible!  So, if there is only *one* instance of Excel open on the machine, then use `Application.visible = true`.  However, it may be that other spreadsheets are open.  If this is the case, then only hide the current workbook.  Hence `ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False` is used after in the `Else` block.

2.  Once Excel has been made invisible, we load up our forms.  These are windows which provide a front end GUI for interaction with the user.  I am thus able to create a proper application from Excel almost without any indication that Excel is running behind the scenes.

3.  Once the user has finished, he presses an exit button which I have called cmdExit.  You can see the code bend this button below.  It unloads the GUI forms and makes Excel visible again for the user.  This is similar to what you want to achieve.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Stop

    ' Hide Excel...
'    ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
    If Workbooks.Count < 2 Then
        Application.Visible = False
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
    End If

    Load frmMain
    frmMain.Show vbModal

End Sub


Private Sub cmdQuit_Click()

    'ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
    Application.Visible = True
    Unload frmMoreOccupationLines
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

I think the reason you might be seeing more than one workbook may be because you have inadvertantly left previous instances of Excel still open but hidden (invisible).  They have not been unloaded and still remain in memory.  Does that make sense?  So when you do `Application.visible=true`, you are seeing all the previous instances which you did not properly quit.  So a solution for m you may be to ensure you implement a proper unload and exit strategy in your code.

So I guess you might be looking for a solution like as shown below:

```
Sub Test()
    If Workbooks.Count < 2 Then
        Application.Visible = False
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
    End If

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

    If Workbooks.Count < 2 Then
        Application.Visible = True
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub cmdQuit_Click()
    Application.Visible = True
    'Unload Me
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: And what are these userforms? I'm trying to hide Excel during run-time, then have only my main workbook re-appear afterwards.

Comment: @dwirony: I have re-edited my answer so it addresses your question.  Basically, my userforms are forms I created to provide a GUI front end for user interaction.  As I hide my Excel, I am effectively creating a Windows application powered by Excel VBA with little to give it away that there is an Excel spreadsheet behind the application.  Hope this makes it clearer for you!

Comment: No dice - this just hides the workbook, not the application. I'm trying to complete hide the application during run-time. There are no previous version of Excel open, I've checked all the processes in task manager. One of the re-appearing workbooks is my `PERSONAL.xlsb`, the other one is unknown.

Comment: @dwirony ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False will hide the workbook.    Application.visible = false DOES hide the entire EXCEL application.  No trace of it remains visible!  I promise you.  I have used this code successfully.  I can email it to you so you can run it and see for yourself.  What do you mean by application?  Are you trying to hide some additional UI forms?

Comment: Yes, `Application.Visible = False` hides the application just fine, but when I use `Application.Visible = True` I get 3 instances of the application. Your code that you've just provided is not hitting `Application.Visible = False` because I *technically* have two workbooks open - my main workbook and the `PERSONAL.xlsb` which opens automatically.

Comment: @dwirony In that case, simply take Application.Visible = False outside of the if-else block.  That is, get rid of the if-else block and replace it with Application.visible = False.   The if else is only there so as not to affect other open and unconnected spreadsheets.

Comment: There won't be any other open spreadsheets when this code runs.